# jquery postcode anywhere api does not return value

Tags: jquery, api, return

I am using postcode anywhere lookup service the code below allow me to console log the value but does not return it as an object

```
function StoreFinder_Interactive_RetrieveNearest_v1_10(Key, Origin, MaximumItems, MaximumRadius, MaximumTime, DistanceType, LocationLists) {

    $.getJSON("http://services.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/StoreFinder/Interactive/RetrieveNearest/v1.10/json3.ws?callback=?",
    {
        Key: Key,
        Origin: Origin,
        MaximumItems: MaximumItems,
        MaximumRadius: MaximumRadius,
        MaximumTime: MaximumTime,
        DistanceType: DistanceType,
        LocationLists: LocationLists
    },
    function (data) {
        // Test for an error
        if (data.Items.length == 1 && typeof(data.Items[0].Error) != "undefined") {
            // Show the error message
            alert(data.Items[0].Description);
        }
        else {
            // Check if there were any items found
            if (data.Items.length == 0)
                alert("Sorry, there were no results");
            else {
                // PUT YOUR CODE HERE
                //FYI: The output is a JS object (e.g. data.Items[0].YourId), the keys being:
                distance = data.Items[0].Distance;

                console.log(distance);
               // name = data.Items[0].Name;

                //YourId
                //Name
                //Description
                //Distance
                //Time
                //Easting
                //Northing
                //Latitude
                //Longitude
                return distance;

            }
        }
    });
}
```

so my call

```
   var data = StoreFinder_Interactive_RetrieveNearest_v1_10("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", $('#postcode').val() );
console.log("data is"+data)
```

gives data as undefined.

Answer (score 1):

That is because $.getJSON is asynchronous and doesn't immediately return a value before the next function is called.

So, in your example:

```
var data = StoreFinder_Interactive_RetrieveNearest_v1_10("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", $('#postcode').val() );
console.log("data is"+data)
```

Your code will move on to console.log() with data still undefined because your StoreFinder function doesn't immediately return a value.

The idiomatic way to handle this in javascript is to include a callback function in your arguments to your StoreFinder function that will execute once your request is complete.

Here's a generic example that uses $.getJSON:

```
function StoreFinderFunction(options, callback) {
  $.getJSON(options, function(data) {
    // Do what you need to do when you receive the data
    callback(data);
  });
}
```

Then to log your result:

```
StoreFinderFunction(my_options, function (data) {
  // This will now log your data 
  console.log("data is"+data);
});
```